# Сокращение времени работы программмы

Tags: python, алгоритм, сортировка

Всем привет! При выполнении задачи я попадаю в time limit, а идей по сокращению времени/кода так и не появилось. Дайте совет/подсказку, в какую сторону думать, пожалуйста)

> Входные данные: Первая строка - целое число n. В следующих n строках -
> пары целых чисел через табуляцию(уникальный ID≤10^6 и параметр≤10^9).
>
> Задача - отсортировать входные данные по невозрастанию параметра,
> причём сортировка должна быть устойчивой (при равенстве параметров
> сохраняется порядок ID)
>
> Ограничение памяти: 64 Mb
>
> Ограничение времени: 1 секунда
>
> Вывод: n пар чисел через tab, каждая пара в новой строке.

Код:

```
n = int(input())
c = input().split()
for i in range(1, n):
    a, b = input().split()
    if int(b) > int(c[1]):
        c.insert(0, b)
        c.insert(0, a)
    elif int(b) <= int(c[len(c) - 1]):
        c.append(a)
        c.append(b)
    else:
        for j in range(0, len(c) - 3):
            if int(b) <= int(c[j + 1]) and int(b) > int(c[j + 3]):
                c.insert(j + 2, b)
                c.insert(j + 2, a)
                break
for i in range(0, (len(c) // 2), 1):
    print(c[2 * i],  c[2 * i + 1], sep = '\t')
```

Ввод и вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно, пожалуйста, пример входа и выхода

Comment: Добавил в условие

Comment: Я бы попробовал поиграться с функцией `sort`, если в нее передавать `key=`, то можно настроить сортировку, что-то вроде: `items = [list(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(int(input()))]` + `items.sort(key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Встроенная в Python сортировка (sort, sorted) является устойчивой (по крайней мере с версии 2.2), поэтому нужно её и применить с ключом по второму элементу кортежа (в кортежах пары (id,par))

```
sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Если по какой-то причине встроенный sort не дозволяется, то нетрудно сделать сортировку слиянием (mergesort)

Comment: UPD. Попробовал такой вариант кода:
`items = [list(map(int, input().split())) for items in range(int(input()))]`

`items.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse = True)`

`for x in items:
    print(x[0], x[1], sep='\t')`
Получаю time limit на тесте с n=95023

Comment: Код лучше показывать в отредактированное вопросе, здесь плохо читается, но на вид все нормально. Померяйте, сколько времени занимает чтение и организация списка, сколько сортировка, сколько вывод для большого n